# How to keep fancybox content on callback?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have a page with many radio button that are hidden and shown when the fancybox is called.

Here's my js code to call the content into the fancybox when trigged.

```
 $("#serviceType").change(function() {
    var selectedOption_ID = $("#serviceType option:selected").attr("value");
    if (selectedOption_ID == "7"){
      $.fancybox({
        'content': $("#advancedInspection").html()
      });
    }
  });
```

Some of the code inside the #advancedInspection:

```
<div id="advancedInspection" style="display:none;">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="900">
        <tr style="text-align:left">
            <td>DEVANT</td>
            <td>Oui <input type="radio" name="tlDevant1" value="yes"/></td>
            <td>Non <input type="radio" name="tlDevant1" value="no"/></td>
            <td>DEVANT</td>
            <td>Oui <input type="radio" name="tlDevant2" value="yes"/></td>
            <td>Non <input type="radio" name="tlDevant2" value="no"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:left">
            <td>DOS</td>
            <td>Oui <input type="radio" name="tlDos1" value="yes"/></td>
            <td>Non <input type="radio" name="tlDos1" value="no"/></td>
            <td>DOS</td>
            <td>Oui <input type="radio" name="tlDos2" value="yes"/></td>
            <td>Non <input type="radio" name="tlDos2" value="no"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:left">
            <td>HAUT DE DOS</td>
            <td>Oui <input type="radio" name="tlHautDos" value="yes"/></td>
            <td>Non <input type="radio" name="tlHautDos" value="no"/></td>
            <td>TAILLE</td>
            <td>Oui <input type="radio" name="tlTaille" value="yes"/></td>
            <td>Non <input type="radio" name="tlTaille" value="no"/></td>
        </tr>
....
   </table>
</div>
```

Everything's works fine except that when I close that fancybox and call it back again, all radio button that were selected are gone. I need to recheck them 1 by 1.

Is there a way to use Fancybox to load a DIV of the page in it and keep the modification you do?

Please note that the #serviceType is a dropdown menu with all options. And when the option with id #7 is chose, it fire the fancybox with the content of #advancedInspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add functions to the `onComplete` and `onCleanup` callbacks to restore and save the input values, respectively. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UagVd/13/) and the code:

```
var form = $("#advancedInspection"),
    inputs = form.find('input'),
    saveValues = function() {
        $('#fancybox-content input').each(function(i) {
            inputs.eq(i).attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    },
    restoreValues = function() {
        $('#fancybox-content input').each(function(i) {
            this.checked = inputs.eq(i).is(':checked');
        });
    };

$('button').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'content': form.html(),
        onComplete: restoreValues,
        onCleanup: saveValues
    });
});
```